# Having trouble making AJAX requests to an express server when using React Router

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I'm struggling a bit with making ajax requests to pull data from a MongoDB database.

The App is written using React, using React-Router for routing and sitting on an Express server. I'm using `whatwg-fetch` to handle ajax calls.

When I try to make the ajax call, I get the following error:

```
parsing failed:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I think the problem lies with React-Router. When I navigate directly to the URL specified in the ajax call, I get the following error:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/levelsList" did not match any routes
```

So it looks as though React-Router is intercepting the request to the url and trying to deliver the page, which doesn't exist in the context of React-Router. So, how do I bypass React-Router for ajax calls and use the Express router instead?

Here's more of the code:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const path = require('path');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./webpack.dev.config')

//Mongoose Schema

const Level = require('./data/models/Level');

//DB SETUP

mongoose.connect('mongodb://Localhost/Academy');

// SERVER SETUP

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');

compiler=webpack(config);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {colors: true}
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
    log: console.log
}));

app.use(express.static(publicPath));



//Routes

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(publicPath, 'index.html'));
})

app.get('/levelsList', function(req, res){
    console.log('test');
    Level.find({})
        .exec(function(err, levels){
            if (err){
                res.send('error has occurred');
            } else {
                console.log(levels);
                res.json(levels);
            }
        })
})


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

Here's the action creator which makes the ajax call, which should then dump the info into my redux store

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';


export function qualDetails(){

    const data = fetch('/levelsList')
        .then(function(res){
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(function(json){
            console.log('parsed json: ', json)
        })
        .catch(function(ex){
            console.log('parsing failed: ', ex) // This is where the error message is coming from
        });
    console.log(data);
    return {
        type: 'COURSE_DETAILS',
        payload: data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to put your `app.get(*)` after your route declaration.

```
//Routes
app.get('/levelsList', function(req, res){
    console.log('test');
    Level.find({})
        .exec(function(err, levels){
            if (err){
                res.send('error has occurred');
            } else {
                console.log(levels);
                res.json(levels);
            }
        })
})

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(publicPath, 'index.html'));
})

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
```

As far as i can remmember, express will try all the paths in the exact same order. 
Actually `/levelslist` will match your `get(*)` and  then react will try to route on `/levelslist`

I usualy expose my statics front app under `/app` and my api routes under `/api` prefixes. It really help to prevent any confusion

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't seem to have worked - I'm still getting the same error messages

Comment: @Chris Updated my answer, i just realized that it was your `app.get('*')` that match your route, and redirect to react. React then try to route with react-router

Comment: Aah - after your edit, it seems to be working! Brilliant, thanks!